# Why am I getting a Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, itext

I am using itextsharp and trying to use

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer);
```

which is a static method but I always get this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 178: 
Line 179:            //create a new action to send the document to our new destination.
Line 180:            PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer);
Line 181:
Line 182:            //set the open action for our writer object


Source File: VoucherService.cs    Line: 180

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetPageReference(Int32 page) +326
   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(Int32 page, PdfDestination dest, PdfWriter writer) +49
   OnlineStudentPlanner.Framework.Services.VoucherService.SetupPdfDoc(String invoiceNumber, String logoPath, Document doc, MemoryStream memoryStream, PdfWriter writer, PdfPTable& table) in VoucherService.cs:180
   OnlineStudentPlanner.Framework.Services.VoucherService.GenerateVouchers(Int32 qty, Int32 voucherSize, String invoiceNumber, String logoPath, Int32 siteWideQty, IEnumerable`1 validDomains, Boolean siteWideVoucher) in VoucherService.cs:55
   OnlineStudentPlanner.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.GenerateVouchers(GenerateVouchersVm vm) in Admin\Controllers\HomeController.cs:52
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

here is my code that I have

```
Document doc = new Document();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfPTable table;

doc.Open();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
writer.CloseStream = false;

SetupPdfDoc(invoiceNumber, logoPath, doc, memoryStream, writer, out table);

private  void SetupPdfDoc(string invoiceNumber, string logoPath, Document doc,  MemoryStream memoryStream, PdfWriter writer, out PdfPTable table)
{
    PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, doc.PageSize.Height, 0.75f);
    doc.AddTitle(String.Format("Vouchers-{0}", invoiceNumber));
}
```

Comment: `doc` and `memoryStream` are empty. Is that expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to operate on an empty PDF document without any pages.

Changing the following three lines:

```
        doc.Open();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
```

to:

```
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();
        doc.NewPage();
```

should resolve your issue.

Comment: I will try that but if I move my upper code into the same method. It all works and I do not need to do NewPage();

Comment: In that case, try removing the PDFTable output parameter. That's the only thing I can see that may be causing that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have You checked if pdfDest and writer are not null? It throws exception at line:

```
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetPageReference(Int32 page) +326
```

I would assume that writer is not null, so either pdfDest is null or there is bug in iTextSharp, and passing wrong page is causing an exception (wrong exception, it should be OutOfBounds or something).

Comment: From what I see nothing is null. It seems to have problems with doc even though that is not null as well.

Comment: Then it seems there is bug in iTextSharp. GetPageReference() should check if page parameter is valid(f.e. less than number of pages), it propably doesn't and that is causing an exception. If that's the case You should check if page parameter is less than page count. Also, remember that in most, if not all, cases, in programming, numbering starts with 0, not 1 (I'm assuming here You want to go to first page)